# Do any of the Avengers actually wear the Avengers logo?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

IIRC, the only time I've ever seen the Avengers logo in any of the MCU films is on the rooftop of HQ. Other than that, I don't think any of the team members wear the logo on their outfits, and, it's never used to signal the team (as perhaps Batman's bat-signal *does* use his logo).

Have any of the Avengers team members been shown actually wearing/using the Avengers logo?

[image]

Comment: 16:09 before the end of Civil War (Stark is somewhere... maybe HQ, but doesn't appear to be the rooftop.)  I suppose you could say that Stark is "using" the logo (by reflecting upon it)

Comment: In response to the first line of the Question:  [Stark Tower](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers_Tower) (in New York) has shown up in a couple of movies with the Avenger's logo visible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Yes

Captain America has this on his shoulder in *Age of Ultron*.

[image]

Comment: Hm.. why would Captain America be the only one to wear the logo? Is he also the official team leader?

Comment: Probably because it fits with his motif. He used to have an "A" logo anyway...it's not really appropriate for the others. In the MCU he's not the *official* leader but is the *tactical* leader.

Comment: @Charles He is, according to Tony - As they arrive back having acquired the Sceptre, Tony tells Maria Hill that Steve is "the boss, I just make everyone look cool and pay for everything"...

Comment: @Charles: “Is he also the official team leader?” Well, he’s not called _Assistant Deputy Regional Manager_ America, is he?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - captain is a pretty lowly rank.

Comment: @Davor: you see anyone in the Avengers with a higher rank? Did Hawkeye suddenly get promoted to General? Are we meant to pretend that Air Force ranks count just to be nice to Rhodey?

Comment: The ranks are irrelevant, The Avengers is not a military group. Cap is the moral and tactical leader....at least in the MCU...becuase the others recognise his leadership abilities.

Comment: @Davor Captain is a pretty high rank in the Navy.

Comment: @Harper - he's clearly not a captain of a ship.

Comment: Assistant *to* the Deputy Regional Manager America

Answer (score 14):

A quick google found this image:
[image: Captain America in Age of Ultron]

Where Cap clearly has the Avengers logo on his shoulder.  I'll update if I find pics of the others